# Domain of a function quick question

Tags: calculus

$$f(x)=\arcsin\left(\frac{x-1}{2x}\right)$$
We need to find the domain of this function.

My try:

$$-1\leq \frac{x-1}{2x} \leq 1 $$

We can split this into
$$-1\leq \frac{x-1}{2x} \quad\text{and} \quad\frac{x-1}{2x} \leq 1$$
My idea is to solve for this two inequalities and then take the intersection of them both.

$$-2x\leq x-1\\
-3x\leq -1\\
x\geq\frac{1}{3}$$

$$x-1 \leq 2x\\
-1 \leq x$$

By doing the intersection I get the wrong answer which is: $x\geq\frac{1}{3}$

What have I done wrong?

Comment: I believe what we want is the part where range of $\frac{x-1}{2x}$ lies between -1 and 1.I just wrote this to the wolfram alpha and result was x<-1 or x>1/3

Comment: @OğuzhanKılıç Yes exactly, I have done the same, I just don't get it how to get $x<-1$, I think that the triple inequality is giving me hard thoughts.

Comment: Hint: graph $y = (x - 1)/(2x)$ and see when it's above the line $y = -1$. This should point to where the error in your algebra is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:
You forgot the case when x is negative and then, you can't multiply the inequality with $2x$.You need to change the direction of the inequality.

So take by the 2 cases:

1.$x>0$

2.$x<0$

If you still don't get it to work, tell me and I will come up with a complete solution

Comment: I guess it's more optimal to look it as a rational function then ?

Comment: What I mean is to subtract 1 and leave 2x in the denominator.

Comment: Yes.That is another very good idea

Comment: And then you only need to find the interval of $x$ for which the fraction is pozitive/negative

Answer (score 2):

The two inequalities can be handled at once as following without inviting mistakes :

For $x \neq 0$
$$\frac{x-1}{2x} \in [-1,1]$$
$$\frac{1}{2} - \frac{1}{2x} \in [-1,1]$$
$$-\frac{1}{2x} \in [\frac{-3}{2},\frac{1}{2}]$$
$$\frac{1}{x} \in [-1,3]$$
Taking reciprocal (and changing the direction),
$$x \in \; ]-1,\frac{1}{3}[$$

That is $$x \le -1 \vee x \ge 1/3$$

Comment: Why does the direction have to change ?

Comment: When you take reciprocal, eg, if $y > 2$ then $1/y < 1/2$. The direction of inequality/interval changes.

Comment: I understand, I have never seen this notation: $x \in \; ]-1,\frac{1}{3}[$.
Very sophisticated solution.

Comment: It means same as $(-\infty, \infty) - [-1,1/3]$. But if you could change direction of inequalities just by inverting brackets and you're avoiding any possible mistakes; I'd call it easy rather than sophisticated. :) Its just a new notation for you, but you can use it now.

Answer (score 1):

Here it is another approach for the sake of curiosity.

I would start with squaring both sides as it is done next:

\begin{align*}
\left|\frac{x-1}{2x}\right| \leq 1 & \Longleftrightarrow \left(\frac{x-1}{2x}\right)^{2} \leq 1\\\\
& \Longleftrightarrow \frac{x^{2} - 2x + 1 - 4x^{2}}{4x^{2}} \leq 0\\\\
& \Longleftrightarrow \frac{3x^{2} + 2x - 1}{4x^{2}} \geq 0
\end{align*}

We may now study the behavior of the function at the numerator.

To begin with, let us rearrange its expression:
\begin{align*}
3x^{2} + 2x - 1 & = \left(3x^{2} + 2x + \frac{1}{3}\right) - \frac{4}{3}\\\\
& = \left(\sqrt{3}x + \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}\right)^{2} - \frac{4}{3}
\end{align*}

Consequently, the solution set to problem proposed is given by
\begin{align*}
3x^{2} + 2 x - 1 \geq 0 & \Longleftrightarrow \left(\sqrt{3}x + \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}\right)^{2} \geq \frac{4}{3}\\\\
& \Longleftrightarrow \left(\sqrt{3}x + \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}} \geq \frac{2}{\sqrt{3}}\right)\vee\left(\sqrt{3}x + \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}} \leq -\frac{2}{\sqrt{3}}\right)\\\\
& \Longleftrightarrow \left(x \geq \frac{1}{3}\right)\vee\left(x \leq -1\right)
\end{align*}

Since both intervals does not contain the value $x = 0$, we conclude the sought domain is given by
\begin{align*}
D_{f} = (-\infty,-1]\cup\left[\frac{1}{3},+\infty\right)
\end{align*}

Hopefully this helps!